# Using of esriFieldTypeDate field in Add Features REST service?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, rest

I need to use Add Features REST service to add a new record to a table in an ArcSDE geodatabase.

One of the field is type of esriFieldTypeDate, but I don't know how to populate this field in JSON script. An example is as follows:

```
[
    {
      "attributes" : {
        "LOCATION_ID" : 30,
        "LOCATION_NAME" : "SDAF",
        "LOCATION_STATUS" : "IN USE",
        "GEOMETRY_ID" : 30,
        "CREATE_DATE" : "2008/06/16 00:00:00 AM"
      }
    }
]
```

Column "CREATE_DATE" is of esriFieldTypeDate type. But the above JSON ended up with an error.

Comment: What does the json returned for a Query look like for CREATE_DATE?

Comment: Just hit the same wall. Here's what a Date field looks like as returned in JSON from our server: ReviewedDate: 1384300800000   Looks like millis since 1/1/1970 as noted in the answer below

Answer (score 3):

attributes: The feature attributes. It is a JSON object that contains a dictionary of name-value pairs. The names are the feature field names. The values are the field values and they can be any of the standard JSON types - string, number and boolean. Note that date values are encoded as numbers. The number represents the number of milliseconds since epoch (January 1, 1970) in UTC.

That is what the [Esri REST endpoint help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005700000070000000) says.